# Multiple modules with same build type

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a gradle android project with two modules:

- Wear
- App (which is the phone app)

In my gradle configuration I have different build types. The defaults (debug and release, each with custom settings), and dev and beta build type (also with custom signing, custom proguard and custom applicationIdSuffix.

What I now want to do is to build the app package with for example the buildType beta (gradle clean assembleBeta). That starts building the app in beta, sees that it has a dependency to wear, and starts building wear. BUT here's the problem. The wear module is being built with the release build type instead of the same beta-build-type I used to initiate the build.

The custom build type configuration is exactly the same on the two modules, and thus manually building the wear module with beta build type does work. But having a wear module built with beta and packaged inside the app module also built with beta does not work.

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to always build `Wear` module with release build type, no matter what the build type of your `App` module is?

Comment: No that is how it default works. I do an aasembleBeta on app, and it builds the wear dependency in assembleRelease. What I want is that the wear module is also built on assembleBeta. Otherwise my package names do not match...

Comment: Another question - what is different between beta and production app?

Comment: Package name and backend it connects on. Client requires this kind of setup

Comment: Ok. The server name is not important for watch app but package name is probably (if you want to have two apps - dev and production - on the same device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know answer if it is possible to connect/link build variants from one project to another.

But here workaround. You can build app with dependency not to project but to already built apk (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html). So you have to build wear app variant separately and include that artifact to your app artifact.

```
dependencies {
  ...
  wearApp files('/path/to/wearable_app.apk')
}
```

**UPDATE**
Actually it is possible:

```
productFlavors {
        dev {
        }

        prod {
        }
    }
...
devWearApp project(path: ':wearable', configuration: 'devRelease')
prodWearApp project(path: ':wearable', configuration: 'prodRelease')
```

Credits to Muzei app https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/blob/master/main/build.gradle

Comment: I thought about that but that's not handy at all. A tool like Gradle should be able to get something as easy as that done. But didn't find in the documentation anything to get it done so far... Maybe it's a well hidden feature...